# can't ssh into remote host with root, password incorrect

Tags: ssh, password, root, vpn, su

I have a remote host,
previously I can ssh into it with root and password

```
ssh root@remote_host
```

or I ssh into it first using a regular user account

```
ssh esolve@remote_host
```

and then `su root` and input password

but today, in both ways, my password is always incorrect, like

```
[esolve@local esolve]$  ssh root@remote_host
root@remote_host's password: 
Permission denied, please try again.
```

or

```
[esolve@remote_host ~]$ su root
Password: 
su: incorrect password
```

related information:

1. I can use this password to log in with root if I operated locally on that remote machine today.
2. I ssh into is via VPN

Why did this happen? How can I solve this problem?

Comment: If you are able to su root successfully but cannot log in as root via SSH, then the system administrator likely disabled root SSH access which is always a good idea.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Do you have ssh as root disabled? Check your sshd configuration (possibly `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`) and look for the line `PermitRootLogin no`. Change the `no` to `yes` and restart sshd (most likely either `service ssh restart` or `service sshd restart`).

Some distributions (e.g., Ubuntu) default to `without-password` for `PermitRootLogin` such that root login is allowed via public key authentication, but not with a password.

Comment: what distribution? Also, are you logging in on a local terminal or trying to ssh as root to localhost? PermitRootLogin doesn't care if you start at localhost.

Answer (score 5):

For first time if you are access SSH remote server in new system, just update it. Open the ssh configuration file,

```
# vim /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

***PermitRootLogin without-password***

change to

***PermitRootLogin yes***

Restart your ssh service.

restart ssh server.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, this 73rd line in sshd_config didn't allow any user to login with password. No where found this solution, just struck it with luck. Either comment it out (or make it 'yes'):

`KbdInteractiveAuthentication no`

This prohibits keyboard interaction while logging into remote server.