# 'Open in Remote Terminal' in sftp root user not showing up

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, terminal, remote, sftp

After opening file manager, clicking on the other-locations tab and open an sftp connection. I try to open a remote terminal by right-clicking on the folder and selecting `Open in Remote Terminal`. Instead of opening under the user `root` of the ubuntu I'm trying to connect, it opens the user under the name of my current computer.

`my-computer-user@192.168.2.208's password:`

instead of

`root@192.168.2.208's password:`

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to fix this:

1. Run the following command:

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config
   ```
2. Change the variable `PermitRootLogin` to `yes` (uncomment if necessary)
3. Save changes & restart the computer.

---

<sup>[Thanks to the source to the solution.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/79451/451050)</sup>